# How do I get the corresponding row for a RowsetID?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We're faced with the following error when a query runs against a partitioned table with Read-Only file groups:

> The index "ix_my_index" for table "dbo.my_table" (RowsetId 72057600379912192) resides on a read-only filegroup ("MyFileGroup"), which cannot be modified

How would I identify which row the query is trying to modify from the RowsetID?

I know `sysrowsets` used to exist, but doesn't seem to in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: You can still query it but with a DAC checkout https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179503.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a `partition_id` to me, not "a row." You can start to get an idea of what values might be stored in that partition through the following:

```
SELECT partition_number
  FROM sys.partitions
  WHERE partition_id = 72057600379912192;
```

Then you'll have to look at the partition function / scheme to tell where the boundaries are for that specific partition.

I don't think `sys.sysrowsets` is going to tell you anything that `sys.partitions` won't. It's unfortunate that the product interchanges words like `partition_id`, `hobt_id`, and `RowsetId` so carelessly.

Comment: Ah, that would make much more sense!